Filter nested JSON by multiple keys
I am pretty new to JavaScript but very new to JSON and objects.
I need to filter a nested JSON on multiple keys.
I am trying
const filteredEntries = oldJSON.filter(([key, value]) => {
  return key === "id" && key === "label" && key==="options"
});

but I get object is not iterable 
I am aware there are many questions of this type, but I could not get any of them to work with my particular JSON format.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks
 const oldJSON = [
 {
 "id": "c3c6f410f58e5836431b473ebcf134756232d04f2bf35edff8",
 "component": "checkbox",
 "customFields": [

 ],
 "index": 0,
 "label": "Sector2",
 "options": {
  "62f92fab79ac81d933765bd0bbc4a1f5ea26cb3a088bcb4e6e": {
    "index": 0,
    "value": "Bob",
    "label": "Bob",
    "count": 1
  },
  "2fe91aa3567c0d04c521dcd2fc7e40d7622bb8c3f594d503da": {
    "index": 1,
    "value": "Student",
    "label": "Student",
    "count": 1
  },
  "c59ea1159f33b91a7f6edc6925be5e373fc543e4": {
    "index": 2,
    "value": "BBB",
    "label": "BBB",
    "count": 1
  },
  "c59ea1159f33b91a7f6edc6925be5e373fc54AAA": {
    "index": 3,
    "value": "Orange Duck",
    "label": "Orange Duck",
    "count": 1
  }
},
"required": false,
"validation": "/.*/",
"imported": false
},
{
"id": "f794c6a52e793ee6f5c42cd5df6b4435236e3495e951709485",
"component": "textInput",
"customFields": [

],
"index": 1,
"label": "Brown Cow",
"options": {
},
"required": false,
"validation": "/.*/",
"imported": false
},
{
"id": "f794c6a52e793ee6f5c42cd5df6b4435236e3495e95170ZZZ",
"component": "textInput",
"customFields": [

],
"index": 1,
"label": "Red Fish",
"options": {
},
"required": false,
"validation": "/.*/",
"imported": false
},
];

const filteredEntries = oldJSON.filter(([key, value]) => {
return key === "id" && key === "label" && key==="options"
});

console.log(filteredEntries )

expected output is
[ {
"id": "c3c6f410f58e5836431b473ebcf134756232d04f2bf35edff8",
   "label": "Sector2",
   "options": {
  "62f92fab79ac81d933765bd0bbc4a1f5ea26cb3a088bcb4e6e": {
    "index": 0,
    "value": "Bob",
    "label": "Bob",
    "count": 1
  },
  "2fe91aa3567c0d04c521dcd2fc7e40d7622bb8c3f594d503da": {
    "index": 1,
    "value": "Student",
    "label": "Student",
    "count": 1
  },
  "c59ea1159f33b91a7f6edc6925be5e373fc543e4": {
    "index": 2,
    "value": "BBB",
    "label": "BBB",
    "count": 1
  },
  "c59ea1159f33b91a7f6edc6925be5e373fc54AAA": {
    "index": 3,
    "value": "Orange Duck",
    "label": "Orange Duck",
    "count": 1
  }
  },
  {
  "id": "f794c6a52e793ee6f5c42cd5df6b4435236e3495e951709485",
  "label": "Brown Cow",
  "options": {
  }
  },
  {
  "id": "f794c6a52e793ee6f5c42cd5df6b4435236e3495e95170ZZZ",
  "label": "Red Fish",
  "options": {
  }];


Your main problem is in your condition, Your condition key === "id" && key === "label" && key === "options" is logically impossible because a single key cannot be equal to multiple different strings at the same time.
The code should be like:
const filteredEntries = oldJSON.filter(item =>
        item.id && item.label && item.options
    ).map(({ id, label, options }) => ({ id, label, options }));

console.log(filteredEntries);


Ali this gives options:       { '62f92fab79ac81d933765bd0bbc4a1f5ea26cb3a088bcb4e6e': [Object],        '2fe91aa3567c0d04c521dcd2fc7e40d7622bb8c3f594d503da': [Object],        c59ea1159f33b91a7f6edc6925be5e373fc543e4: [Object],        c59ea1159f33b91a7f6edc6925be5e373fc54AAA: [Object] } }  how to keep the values of the options?

@Einarr that is weird can you try this: console.log(JSON.stringify(filteredEntries, null, 2)); and let me know the output.
